# JBOSS 7.1, Securing EJB3 Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I have an EJB web service that is secured with a security domain that has database login configuration where each user is mapped to a set of roles

My problem is that JBOSS reject any user access that doesn't have the first web service method role !!!

example:

```
@SecurityDomain("MyWS")
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName = "MyService")
@WebContext(authMethod = "BASIC", urlPattern = "/*", secureWSDLAccess = false)
@RolesAllowed("CLIENT")
public class MyService {

      @RolesAllowed("R1")
      public void method1() { ... }

      @RolesAllowed("R2")          
      public void methdo2() { ... }

      @RolesAllowed("R3")
      public void methdo3() { ... }

}
```

Now if I have a user with roles Client, R1 and R2, everything is OK, but If I have a user with roles Client and R3 only, the user access is always rejected by JBOSS, I must assign the user to role "R1" too

and the strange thing is that the "mandatory" roles is the role of the 1st method in the class, I mean if I switched the location of method1 and method2, then "R2" will be the mandatory role that all users should be assigned to

How is that, is there something I am missing here ?